# jsf passing a string made from one bean to a string in another bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In my jsf 2.0 code when you complete a form it takes account of all the "error" values you your stated in one form and adds it to a string buffer when the commandbutton is pressed then i covert it to a string. Now what i want is for this string to go to the next bean as a value so that the text area input on the next jsf page would have that information already added there. But sadly I am drawing a blank on how i would like to make this happen Here is what i have written down so far. I am not getting any kind of error from either pages or beans its just nothing is showing up any help would be appreciated and very well love.

```
public String fillForm(){

    boolean failTest = false;
    String errorCodeForNcpForm = "";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    buffer.append (" ");

    if (!unitSerialValue.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
    {

        buffer.append (1 +  unitSerialValue  ); 
        failTest = true;
        buffer.append("   ");
    }

    if(!screenProValue.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
    {

        buffer.append (2 +  unitSerialValue  );     
        failTest = true; 
        buffer.append("   ");
    }

    if(failTest)
    {
        //gets the whole error code
        errorCodeForNcpForm = buffer.toString(); 

        NcpFormBean ncpForm = new NcpFormBean();

        //Sets the error code to the value
        ncpForm.setproblemQcValue(errorCodeForNcpForm);

        return "ncpFormQc";
    } 

    else
        return "index";
}
```

here is the xhtml section that contains the code for the value.

```
 <b>Problem Description: </b>  
<h:inputTextarea value="#{ncpFormBean.problemQcValue}" id="problemDec" required="true"  cols="30" rows="10"> 
    <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="30" /> 
</h:inputTextarea>  <br/>
<h:message for="problemDec" style="color:red" />
```

The second bean "ncpFormBean" has nothing currently but the standard getters and setters,and both beans are session scope.

Comment: what is the Scope of your first and second bean?

Comment: Both are sessions . the first bean that sends the string and the second string that receives the data are both sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first bean declare the second bean like:

```
// change the value as the name of your real managedbean name
@ManagedProperty(value="#{ncpFormBean}")
private NcpFormBean ncpForm;
```

with the setter of it:

```
public void setNcpForm(NcpFormBean ncpForm) {
        this.ncpForm = ncpForm;
    }
```

now in your fillForm Method:

```
public String fillForm(){
        boolean failTest = false;
        String errorCodeForNcpForm = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();        
        buffer.append (" ");        
        if (!unitSerialValue.equalsIgnoreCase("P")){        
            buffer.append (1 +  unitSerialValue  ); 
            failTest = true;
            buffer.append("   ");
        }

        if(!screenProValue.equalsIgnoreCase("P")){        
            buffer.append (2 +  unitSerialValue  );     
            failTest = true; 
            buffer.append("   ");
        }

        if(failTest){
            //gets the whole error code
            errorCodeForNcpForm = buffer.toString(); 

            this.ncpForm.setproblemQcValue(errorCodeForNcpForm);

            return "ncpFormQc";
        } else
            return "index";
    }
```

the passed data is now reachable in your second bean for the second view (since your beans are session scoped).

**UPDATE:**

lets say you have 2 beans: Bean1 and Bean2 (both are sessionScoped):

if you want to change values

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean1")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean1 {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{bean2}")
    private Bean2 ncpForm;
    ....
}
```

..

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean2")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean2 {
    ....
    ....
}
```

**NOTE:  @ManagedProperty(value="#{bean2}") this value/name MUST be exactly identical to the name here @ManagedBean(name="bean2")**

now the xhtml:

**bean1.xhtml**

```
....
<h:commandButton action="#{bean1.fillForm}"/>
....
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a error from my xhtml file when I add the "this.ncpForm.setProblemQcValue" This is the error i am getting i will update my question with the xhtml code. Note I only get the error when i add that line of code in the fillform method removing clears it up.

    javax.el.ELException: /qcForm.xhtml at line 389 and column 36 action="#{qcFormBean.fillForm()}": java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException - /qcForm.xhtml at line 389 and column 36 action="#{qcFormBean.fillForm()}": java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: guess i will have to ask about that error but i think it seems like this would make sense.

Comment: @GilbertV; do you still have that error?, i'll update my answer!

Comment: you are welcome!. if you need help, write me, we can continue in a chat room

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47457/discussion-between-gilbert-v-and-rami-q)